# How to create a notification bar at bottom of page?

Tags: html

[I want something like this at the bottom of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbyDy.png)

[image]

Just wondering how to create a notification bar at the bottom of the page to push certain types of things to visitors.

Comment: Are you using some libraries such jquery or bootstrap? 
Do the bar can by closed? Please, give more details..

Comment: So what's the problem? Creating something with a grey background? Putting something at the bottom of the page (and by page do you mean "page" or "window" or "page or window, whichever is lower")? You've got a cross there, is your problem making it go away when the cross is clicked?

Comment: I am using bootstrap. I want the bar to be able to be closed and I want it to stay in view at the bottom of the page when the page is scrolled up or down. Floating at the bottom if you will.

Answer (score 8):

You're gonna need 3 things for that, but since your question is just tagged with HTML, I'll skip the Javascript part of it.

For the HTML, you just need something simple like:

```
<div class="notification-bottom">
  <p>Your Message goes <a href="/yourlink">here</a></p>
  <span class="notification-close">X</span>
</div>
```

And then, the css would look like this:

```
.notification-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* Rest of your styling */
}

.notification-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  /* This are approximated values, and the rest of your styling goes here */
}
```

Then you would need some Javascript interaction to close it, wich should be just adding a class with `display: none` on it.

Hope this helps.